# SharePoint List items, UserControls and cookies

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, user-controls

I have another task at hand.   I need to use cookies to read a title of an item from a custom list in SharePoint.  This task is for SharePoint 2010.

I have a container set up that will display the two newest items.  This container is being populated by a usercontrol and is using the ASP:Repeater control.  In this control I have this:

```
<
asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Portal Content") %>' /> &nbsp; <asp:HyperLink ID="hlAssetUrl" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Asset Title") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Asset URL") %>' Target='<%# Convert.ToString(Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Open in New Window")) ? "_blank" : "_top") %>' >
```

I am trying to set the Asset title in the hyper link as the cookie.

I have the GetCookie function and SetCookie function as follows:

```
unction SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {

var today = new Date();

var expire = new Date();

if (nDays == null || nDays == 0) nDays = 1;

expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);

document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue)

+ ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString();

}

function ReadCookie(cookieName) {

var theCookie = " " + document.cookie;

var ind = theCookie.indexOf(" " + cookieName + "=");

if (ind == -1) ind = theCookie.indexOf(";" + cookieName + "=");

if (ind == -1 || cookieName == "") return "";

var ind1 = theCookie.indexOf(";", ind + 1);

if (ind == -1) ind1 = theCookie.length;

return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind + cookieName.length + 2, ind1));

}
```

Any lead way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: How do i make cookie equal to the title that is being brought in by the user control?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't get why you are using javascript to set/get this cookie if you're going to need them severside anyways?

Set

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie") { Value = "Hey", Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), Path = "/" };
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Get

```
if (Page.Request.Cookies.Count > 0)
    var cookie = Page.Request.Cookies["Name of cookie here"].Values;
```

Now you can use it however you please in your usercontrol. Javascript is a bit overkill in this situation, unless of course you disregard postbacks.

Hope this helps :)